# Dataview filters with too many special characters

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

How can I filter data table with string that contains too many special characters? I tried various way with escape sequence but none worked.

Below is my code:

```
DataView dt = Dt_Resut.DefaultView;
dt.RowFilter = query.ToString();
DataTable Dt_Result = dt.ToTable();
```

Where the value of query.ToString() is Special `~@#$%^&*()_+-=[]|:;'/.,<>?  message.

NOTE: 'query' is string builder. It will create string based on search criteria.

Comment: More information is required. What is "too many special characters" for you? What do you want to do with that query string? Check for any character in it, if it occurs in the table? What field in the dataview are you trying to filter?

Comment: Is the string the cell content or the filter? Show us the filter!

Comment: The string given is the search string. It will search in the column that contains text like given string. Eg. Consider a field in data table viz. 'discription' and the value of that field is 'Special `~@#$%^&*()_+-=[]|:;'/.,<>? message'

Comment: It only breaks when you get too many special characters?  That is not even proper syntax for a RowFilter.

Comment: Yes. it breaks when various combinations of special characters are added. like ^&*()_+-=[]|:;'/.,<>?  or +-=[]|:;'/.,